# Are old Apple Earpods capable of providing balanced audio (as defined below)?

Tags: audio, headphones, ear-phones

Do [the old Apple Earpods](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MNHF2AM/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug), i.e. those with 3.5mm plugs, have cables and plugs capable of providing balanced audio?

By balanced audio, I mean, audio transmitted in the form of "two copies of the same incoming audio signal, sometimes referred to as a hot (positive) and cold (negative) signal" providing "common-mode rejection" for noise. (See "[Balanced Vs. Unbalanced Audio: What's The Difference?](https://www.boxcast.com/blog/balanced-vs.-unbalanced-audio-whats-the-difference)" for more details on balanced vs unbalanced audio.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

Balanced stereo requires 5 wires, hot & cold left, hot & cold right, plus ground. It also needs an un-balancing amp in the receiver.

Aside from that, headphones run at much higher voltages than mics & really don't need to run balanced. Also the mic on a headset is high impedance, suitable for short runs only. Balancing a mic signal to be able to send it over long cable runs requires a low impedance mic.